# Determine if $\|f\|=|\int_{0}^1 f(x) \ dx |$ defines a norm in $C([0,1]).$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification, normed-spaces

> Determine if $$\|f\|=|\int_{0}^1 f(x) \ dx |$$ defines a norm in $C([0,1]).$

Let $f,g \in C([0,1])$ such that $f\geqslant g$. Now $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x) \ dx \geqslant \int_{0}^{1}g(x) \ dx \Longrightarrow  |\int_{0}^{1}f(x) \ dx| \geqslant |\int_{0}^{1}g(x) \ dx| \geqslant 0$$ which gives positivity. Now take again $f,g \in C([0,1])$ $$\|f+g\| = |\int_{0}^1f(x)+g(x)  \ dx| \leqslant |\int_{0}^{1}f(x) \ dx| + |\int_{0}^{1}g(x) \ dx| = \|f\| +\|g\|.$$

is this enough to prove the result or am I missing some properties?

Comment: $\|f\|=0$ does not imply that $f=0$.

Comment: If $\|f\|_p = (\int_{a}^{b} |f(x)|^p\,\mathrm{d}x)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ defines a norm on $C([a,b])$ how come this doesn't work? Isn't this just $p=1$? This should be defined for $p \geqslant 1$.

Comment: Please [don't use `\frac` in exponents or limits of integrals](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/290189). It looks bad and confusing, and it rarely appears in professional mathematics typesetting.

Comment: There is a lot of difference between $|\int_0^{1} f(x)dx|$ and $\int_0^{1} |f(x)| dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Take $f:x \mapsto x - 0.5$ as an example.  $\int_0^1 f = 0$, but $f \not\equiv 0$.